# convertir string a objeto para query Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

En una variable obtengo un query de un .JSON que es de tipo string, necesito convertirlo a un objeto para poderlo enviar en el agregate de mongoose, si uso JSON.parse me da error!

Adjunto el código y agradezco la ayuda

```js
const query = `{
    '$match': {
          _id:"5be19d0dfc8dd33587ee8902",
          location:{$size:1}
        }
    },
    {
      '$project': {
        _id: 1,
        idCity:{ $arrayElemAt: [ "location.idCity", 0]},
        idCountry:{ $arrayElemAt: [ "location.idCity", 0]}
      }
  }`;
const formatQuery = query.replace(/'/g,'"')
let queryObj = JSON.parse(formatQuery)

console.log(queryObj)
```

Comment: Empezando por decirte que ese valor es directamente un objeto de javascript, no le hicieron JSON.stringify() por eso que no puedes usar JSON.parse, ¿Tienes control del backend, tienes alguna forma de modificar la estructura de query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El contenido inicial de query está mal formateado, por esa razón el `JSON.parse` no funciona. Además, por lo visto es un query que vas a usar en un `aggregate` de mongo, para lo cual mongo recibe un array, no un objeto.

Aqui te dejo como debería estar formateada la variable `query` para que pueda ser parseada por `JSON.parse` y la puedas usar dentro del `aggregate`.

```js
const query = `[
    {
        "$match": {
            "_id": "5be19d0dfc8dd33587ee8902",
            "location": {
                "$size": 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 1,
            "idCity": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "location.idCity",
                    0
                ]
            },
            "idCountry": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "location.idCity",
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]`;

let queryObj = JSON.parse(query)

console.log(queryObj);
```

Comment: Suponiendo que no puede alterar el contenido recibido ¿Cómo esto responde la pregunta?

Comment: Porqué supones eso? Yo realicé mi respuesta basado en lo que el usuario pregunto. Nunca dijo que la consulta la recibía de ningún lado. Solo dijo que tenía una variable, hasta escribió como la tenía asignada. Si nos ponemos a hacer respuestas basados en suposiciones, podríamos empezar a suponer mil cosas.

Comment: Funciona de maravilla, muchas gracias!